# Is it possible to use Castle MonoRail Routing feature with IIS 5?

Tags: routes, iis-5, castle-monorail

Do I have to go with IIS 6 or higher to use Castle MonoRail Routing feature?

I know casini work but practically we not gonna deploy web app with casini, or do we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the configuration change required is to make requests for all file extensions go through the ASP.net filter (you can check the configuration for the .aspx extension in IIS).

However, for requests for a particular virtual directory, rather than a specific file in that directory, IIS tries to validate that a directory exists before passing through the requests. To work around that, people usually write an ISAPI filter to intercept requests for directories, or map all requests ending in, say, .mr, to the ASP.net engine, and adjust their url presentation strategy.